# Converting strings to dates in R

Tags: r, date, zoo, data-cleaning, panel-data

I have the following dataframe:

```
DF<-data.frame(A=c("US","US","US","US","UK", "UK","UK", "UK"), Year=c("1980Q1","1980Q2","1980Q3","1980Q4", "1980Q1","1980Q2","1980Q3","1980Q4"), Obs=1:8, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF
   A   Year OBs
1 US 1980Q1   1
2 US 1980Q2   2
3 US 1980Q3   3
4 US 1980Q4   4
5 UK 1980Q1   5
6 UK 1980Q2   6
7 UK 1980Q3   7
8 UK 1980Q4   8
```

As you can notice the `DF$Year` is a character vector:

```
str(DF)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A   : chr  "US" "US" "US" "US" ...
 $ Year: chr  "1980Q1" "1980Q2" "1980Q3" "1980Q4" ...
 $ Obs : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

**SCOPE**

I want `DF$Year` to be converted into a date vector, so that R later understand that Iam working with a panel time series data. For your information Q1 is the first quarter and Q4 is the last (fourth).

Comment: Try `libary(zoo); as.Date(as.yearqtr(DF$Year, format = "%YQ%q"))`

Comment: It might make more sense to stick with `zoo::yearqtr` class depending on what you're going to do with the data.